# More characterizations of Baire space

Tags: real-analysis, baire-category

We know there are a bunch of equivalent definitions of Baire space. For example:

Given a metric space $M$.

1.The complement of 1st category set in $M$ is dense in $M$.

For more equivalent definitions, [see:](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Baire_space#/Definition)

And we can prove that if $M \neq \emptyset$ and is a Baire space. M is of the 2nd category itself and the complement of every set of the 1st category in $M$ is of the 2nd category.

So, can we characterize Baire spaces as:

1'. The complement of every set of the 1st category in $M$ is of the 2nd category ?

I can't come up with an example.

Comment: Your condition 1' is plainly equivalent to "M is not of the first category" which is not equivalent to "M is a Baire space". For example, $M=(\mathbb R\setminus(0,1))\cup(\mathbb Q\cap[0,1])$.

Comment: Thanks for your reformulation of my condition 1'.  For the completeness of this question, there is a essentially same question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3777348/549321